# Error while trying to run a MapReduce job on FIWARE-Cosmos using Tidoop REST API

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

I am following [this guide](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/blob/develop/doc/manuals/quick_start_guide_new.md) on Github and I am not able run the example mapreduced job mentioned in [Step 5](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/blob/develop/doc/manuals/quick_start_guide_new.md#step-5-run-your-first-mapreduce-job).

I am aware that this file no longer exists:

`/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar`

And I am aware that the same file can now be found here:

`/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u6.jar`

So I form my call as below:

`curl -v -X POST "http://computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:12000/tidoop/v1/user/$user/jobs" -d '{"jar":"/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u6.jar","class_name":"WordCount","lib_jars":"/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u6.jar","input":"testdir","output":"testoutput"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: $TOKEN"`

The input directory exists in my hdfs user space and there is a file called testdata.txt inside it. The testoutput folder does not exist in my hdfs user space since I know it creates problems.

When I execute this curl command, the error I get is `{"success":"false","error":1}` which is not very descriptive. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been just tested with my user `frb` and a valid token for that user:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:12000/tidoop/v1/user/frb/jobs" -d '{"jar":"/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar","class_name":"wordcount","lib_jars":"/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar","input":"testdir","output":"outputtest"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
{"success":"true","job_id": "job_1460639183882_0011"}
```

Please observe the fat jar with the MapReduce examples in the "new" cluster (computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org) is at `/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar`, as detailed in the documentation. `/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u6.jar` was the fat jar in the "old" cluster (cosmos.lab.fiware.org).

**EDIT 1**

Finally, the user had no account in the "new" pair of clusters of Cosmos in FIWARE LAB (`storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org` and `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org`), where Tidoop runs, but in another "old" cluster (`cosmos.lab.fiwre.org`). Thus, the issue was fixed by simply provisioning an account in the "new" ones.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even though I changed the path to the jar files on my curl command, I get the same response `{"success":"false","error":1}`. The only difference between our curl commands are the user name and the token. The token is valid since I can list, create, delete files and folders. Might this be related with user rights or, a long shot but, my user name?

Comment: Wait a moment... you don't have an account in the new cluster! :) I've seen you have an account in the old one (`cosmos.lab.fiware.org`), but not in the new one (in fact, it is a pair of clusters, `storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org` and `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org`). Please read the section 2 of the QSG for the new cluster (the one you linked) in order to get an account in the new cluster.

Comment: Btw, Tidoop is only avaliable in the new pair of clusters.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can now use the API. An update for the ones who are dealing with the same issue:My problem was not having a user account in the new cluster (storage.cosmos... and computing.cosmos...) I sent an e-mail to the address provided in the section 2 of the QSG about the problem and, once my user was provisioned to the new cluster, I was able to use the API for running Hadoop jobs.